# 3 and 4 way Wall Switches

Tags: electrical

Thank you for your help in the past I’m back changing out switches now in the basement bathroom.

It appears there’s a three-way and four-way in the same junction box with two switches —- can I not convert this to one switch .. As it impedes the placement of vanity mirror ? —or how can I wire the two that I’ve purchased into the existing junction box… (There is no ground attached to the former switches)

The existing 3 way wires are 1 common 1 hot and red and black .. with the hotwire pigtail with the common ?  There are only 3 connections on the new 3-way .

Of course I’m willing to call electrician but trying to save money obviously.[image]

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: In the US, a "3-way" switch means that two different switches control a single set of lights and a "4-way" switch means that there are 3 or more individual switches that control a single set of lights. (Outside the US, they are "2-way" and "3-way", respectively, which makes more sense.) Are you using the term "4-way" to describe the double switch in your picture? Are there actually 2 other switches that control the same lights that these two switches do?

Comment: In addition to an [edit] to the post title, please be very specific in the question itself about exactly what the electrical situation _is_ (the fact that this interferes with a mirror install doesn't really impact the wiring) and what you would like it _to be_.